# How to pass variable value from loop in template Angular?

Tags: angular

I tried to use index `i` from loop in div element like `id="list-{{i}}"`:

```
<div cdkDropList id="list-{{i}}" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['list-{{i}}']"
*ngFor="let group of subGroups; let i = index"></div>
```

But it does not work for me.

Also I tried:

```
cdkDropList id="{{'list-' + i}}" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[{{'list-' + i}}]"
```

Comment: Have you tried `['list-' + i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *interpolate* instead use string concatenation

```
 [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['list-' + i]"
```

Comment: How dinamicly create this? `#doneList="cdkDropList"`? like #doneList_1, #doneList_2

Comment: @OPV, Please elaborate